# Registering a Service Worker through Angular and Spring Boot 2

Tags: angular, spring-boot, angular-service-worker

We have an application that runs on Spring Boot 2. Most of our site is build using Angular 7. Now our scenario is kind of different cause instead of serving the Angular dist files to the server we use Spring Boot 2 to serve the production build files from angular,

So our pipeline generates the Angular production build files (main.js, vendor.js etc etc) and we copy those into our Spring Boot target folder and pack that up and deploy.

That means that although I register a service worker using the `@angular/service-worker` package we serve it using spring boot.

So ultimately the service worker files are being served from the `js/dist` folder i.e: `https://shop.domain.com/js/dist/ngsw-worker.js`

So I register the service worker fine from `/js/dist/ngsw-worker.js` and it all seems to load.

But when I try to add to homesceen I get the error:

```
Site cannot be installed: no matching service worker detected. You may need to reload the page, or check that the service worker for the current page also controls the start URL from the manifest
```

all relavent files to this are served from the `js/dist` folder. Like: `/js/dist/manifest.webmanifest`
`/js/dist/ngsw.json`
`/js/dist/safety-worker.js`

So I read around and found a nice header called `Service-Worker-Allowed`

So in my Spring Boot 2 application I register the following WebFilter

**ServiceWorkerHeaderFilter.java**

```java
package com.company.project.serviceworker;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/js/dist/ngsw-worker.js")
public class AddServiceWorkerSecurityHeaderFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                         FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Service-Worker-Allowed", "/");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }
}
```

The header seems to be working fine and the files seem to load correctly.
In my manifest file I specify the `start_url`

```
"start_url": "/"
```

I don't specify the `scope` anymore since the http header is supposed to override that.
But even if I do specify it the error keeps occurring.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code worked perfectly for me. As I guess you've figured out by now, the problem is scoping.